# python aggregate and create dicts using DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I started learning pandas and stuck at below issue:
My sample data frame is like below

```
id      batchid     batchname
1       101         accounts
2       101         accounts
1       102         finance
2       104         admin
```

I need to create a new data frame which aggregates `batchid` and `batchname` based on `id` like below:

```
id      group_info
1       [{batchid:101, batchname:accounts},{batchid:102, batchname:finance}]
2       [{batchid:101, batchname:accounts},{batchid:104, batchname:admin}]
```

I tried using `DataFrame.apply()` which consumes `DataFrame.stack()` but is giving errors.
Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Lists of dictionaries in a `pandas` dataframe are very inefficient.

Comment: This is the final step, after all calculations are completed and I need to push the dataframe into db.

Comment: Still doesn't explain it fully. You presumably have a function which pushes a dataframe in a specific format into a database. That's probably the bit that needs developing.

Comment: Yes, the below piece of code goes will be a part of the function. Per the application design, I need all properties of a user in the same record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupby` + `to_dict`

```
df.groupby('id')['batchid','batchname'].apply(lambda x : x.to_dict('r')).to_frame('group_info').reset_index()
Out[84]: 
   id                                         group_info
0   1  [{'batchname': 'accounts', 'batchid': 101}, {'...
1   2  [{'batchname': 'accounts', 'batchid': 101}, {'...
```

Comment: @deepawarrier Yw ~ happy coding